# How can I delete query in Inner join

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

$i=$_REQUEST['id'];
$rs=mysqli_query($mysqli,
  "delete en.*, su.code,su.subject, su.descc ,su.unit,su.sem FROM 
   enrollment en INNER JOIN subject su ON su.year = en.year
   WHERE id='$i' and su.sem='First Semester' and en.sem='First Semester'");

if($rs){
    echo'<script>
                   alert("Delete Successfully");
                  
        </script>';

}
else{
    echo'<script>
                   alert("Error in deleting");
                  
       </script>';
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me to my problem I can't even delete the query it always shows Error in deleting. Here's also the code for the delete button

//

Comment: Here;'s the delete button <a class='btn btn-danger  btn-sm' title='Delete' href='del_stu_subject.php?id=$res[id]'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a></td></tr>

Comment: In SQL, a DELETE statement removes rows from tables. What does it mean, for example, to delete code from the table subject?